# redhat 5.8 uses cifs protocol version 1 or 2?

Tags: linux, redhat, cifs

I have one redhat 5.8 server and i would like to know if the server uses the cifs protocol versiorn 1 or 2.

```
I was looking trough /sys and /proc, but i didn't found nothing, my question is, how can i find the version of cifs used by redhat 5?
```

Answer (score 2):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.8 is packaged with Samba 3.0 and 3.5 (with the "Samba3" name on the RPMs). Neither of those Samba versions supports SMB2. (Samba started [officially supporting SMB2 in version 3.6](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_3.6_Features_added/changed#SMB2_support).)

You may be able to add third-party Samba RPMs (or you can build it yourself) to get SMB2 support in RHEL 5.8, but the stock RPMs from RedHat don't support it.